# WPF Data binding and inventory ObservableCollection treatment

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inventory

Dear fellow enthusiasts (and professionals),

I am relatively new to WPF and novice in C#. I am trying to improve my understanding of these, and therefore working on a small application to replace the excel-based tools for inventory- and order management of the family company.

The code itself is pretty simple, so none of the objects require a lot of computation or memory.
The core of the inventory in this application is an `ObservableCollection<ProductStack> inventory_hardcopy` in a `ProductInventory` singleton class. 
The `ProductStack` class has a `ProductStackCount` (int) property and a `Prod` (`<Product>`) property. 
A `Product` object has `name`, `buyprice`, `sellprice` and `deliveryCost` properties.

When the user begins to record the details of a new order, the UI should load the inventory data. The problem is that any changes are immediately reflected in any `ObservableCollection`, even if the user eventually cancels the dialog window.
I estimate that reverting these changes depending on dialogresult would be way more complex than other solutions.
One such solution would be to clone the `inventory_hardcopy` to `inventory`, while depending on the user feedback it is possible to replace the original `inventory_hardcopy` with the altered clone. This can be implemented via a for cycle and a copy ctor in the ProductStack class. Considering the low complexity and short range of different product objects, these are O(n) processes, but duplications nevertheless.

My current approach is similar, in which, rather then cloning I reference all the products of the `ProductStack`s of the `inventory_hardcopy` in a temporary `ObservableCollection`, called `inventory`, then I copy the `StackCount`s of the `inventory_hardcopy` stacks to `inventory` (this time the order of the stacks matches, therefore the process is O(n)). Finally, when the dialogresult is true, I copy back the `ProductStackCounts` to the `inventory_hardcopy` from `inventory` via an O(n2) process (O(n2), since the temporary collection can be reordered through drag-drop, therefore the corresponding `ProductStack` needs to be looked up before overwriting quantities).

However, to make this work, initiating an `inventory` must be done "manually" by calling `OpenInventory()` method of the `ProductInventory` class, and overwriting `inventory_hardcopy` must be done through calling SaveAndCloseInventory() of the same class.

**My question is: is there a more elegand/more appropriate way to make this?**

My product code fragments:

```
public sealed class ProductInventory
{

public ObservableCollection<ProductStack> Inventory
    {
        get { return inventory; }
        set { inventory = value; }
    }

    ObservableCollection<ProductStack> Inventory_hardcopy
    {
        get { return inventory_hardcopy; }
        set { inventory_hardcopy = value; }
    }

    public void OpenInventory()
    {
        Inventory.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < Inventory_hardcopy.Count; i++)
        {
            Inventory.Add(new ProductStack(Inventory_hardcopy[i].Prod, Inventory_hardcopy[i].ProductStackCount));
        }


    }

    public void SaveAndCloseInventory()
    {        
            for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.Count; i++)
            {
                int idx = 0;
                while (idx < Inventory_hardcopy.Count && Inventory[i].Prod.ProductName != Inventory_hardcopy[idx].Prod.ProductName)
                {
                    idx++;
                }
                Inventory_hardcopy[idx].ProductStackCount = Inventory[i].ProductStackCount;       
            }                       

        // //write to disk here...
    }
//other stuffs are implemented here...
}
```

Comment: You should consider posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, rather than SO.

Comment: If you want this to be legit on Code Review, it should include the code that is currently left out! :) And maybe, just maybe, try to reduce the length of your text, that's kinda long